# Intellisense broken when referencing a VB.NET class library from a ASP.NET Web project in VS2015

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I think the title pretty much says it all! :)

Intellisense broken when referencing a VB.NET class library from a ASP.NET Web project in VS2015.

I have an ASP.NET project with web api 2 (.net 4.5) that references a class library build in VB.NET (don't ask why) using .net 4.

I don't get any intellisense in the ASP.NET project when using types defined in the VB project but it does build!

Any ideas why this might be?

Thanks

// Johan

Comment: Where are your instructions for creating a [minimal, reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Sadly, It works now after multiple restarts, folder cleaning and re-referencing. I cannot create a repro of this.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the file you're referencing is corrupt in some way.

I've run into this a few times, and the only solution I've found is:

1) to get an updated library file, or

2) use the [CreateObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7t9k08y5(v=vs.90).aspx) function to instantiate the object. (Note: it can be tricky to know the actual object name to pass to the function, and not just the file name.)

2 does not work in all cases, but it may be worth a shot.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: The issue actually resolved it self some how. I could build the code, it was just Intellisense not working. I guess I'll never know why.